# How to make a flash 3.0 script play once on MOUSE_OVER (or ROLL_OVER) then once per every such event?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am a newbie trying to do some buttons for my website. I have this actionscript for flash 3.0:

```
this.home.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, function(e:MouseEvent): void{

    play();

});

stop();
```

It works, and the flash plays continuously, but I would like to make it play ONLY ONCE when mouse is over the button.
The `stop();` in the end frame does not work, it stops the flash from playing a second time on mouse over. Tried `ROLL_OVER` and `MOUSE_OVER`, no luck. 
There must be a simple trick, but not getting to it yet.

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10652979/as3-play-movieclip-once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some formatting, I got this:

```
stop()

home.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, manageMouseOver, false, 0, true);
function manageMouseOut(event:MouseEvent):void{
  play();
}
function manageMouseOver(event:MouseEvent):void{
home.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, manageMouseOut, false, 0, true);
  stop();
}
```

It works nicely. 
There are 2 layers, 62 frames (1st layer).
'home' is the button name.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the event listener after it fires the first time. So:

```
this.home.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, function(e:MouseEvent): void{

    this.home.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, arguments.callee);
    play();

});
```

Comment: Thank you Scott, your suggestion helped me in getting it done.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this code works, my luck!

```
stop();
home.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, manageMouseOver, false, 0, true);

 function manageMouseOut(event:MouseEvent):void{
  home.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, manageMouseOver);
  home.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, manageMouseOver, false, 0, true);
  play();
}

function manageMouseOver(event:MouseEvent):void{
  home.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, manageMouseOut);
  home.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, manageMouseOut, false, 0, true);
  stop();
}
```

It does what I needed, play once on mouse over.
Phew!